# Padding on body element

Tags: html, css

Why people add `padding:0;` on body element? I don't see any point in that. All browsers use default `margin:8px;` on body not padding. Am I missing something ? Is there any quirks?

Comment: How do you know that all browsers use default margin:8px; ?

Comment: You might want to read this page http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/body/

Comment: I read this,but this is from 2003.I know in all 5 major browsers body have 8px margin form user agent stylesheet. So setting margin: 0; will place all content to top left corner.No padding needed to set IMO.Even specification says that body must have 8px of margin not padding.
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html

Comment: @Blago: "*This appendix is informative, not normative.*" Your use of the word "must" is incorrect there.

Answer (score 3):

```
  * {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
    }
```

This is part of the "CSS Reset" theory which helps keep your designs consistent across browsers, a very good thing. Unfortunately this is not a good practice. It is very heavy on the rendering agent to apply rules to every single element in the document, especially with large web pages, and this can also destroy a lot of good default styling, especially when you want to have default styled submit buttons.

Comment: Using only "*" is not slow! It's extremley fast. Using something like "h1 *" or "div *" is indeed slow, because the browser reads selectors from right to left to match against elements.

Answer (score 1):

If body { margin: 0; } is used, all other standards compliant browsers (excluding Opera) will set items into the top left corner of the window.

If body { padding: 0; } is used, only Opera (both Mac and Windows) will set items into the top left corner of the window.

The best way to set items into the top left corner of the window is to use body { margin: 0; padding: 0; } which will work for all standards compliant browsers.